# SAP GUI VBS & VBA - Using the RefNummber (Excel) - Copy the data from GridView - Paste back to Excel?

Tags: excel, vba, user-interface, scripting, sap-gui

I am a newbie in VBA & SAP GUI Scripting. I need help implementing the Code into the recorded VBScript.

I have an Excel sheet where the data is imported from SAP transaction code `TM03` into the Excel sheet using the "Referenze Number". This part is working fine.

The code:

```
Public Sub RunGUIScript(currentline As Integer)

Dim W_Ret As Boolean

W_Ret = Attach_Session
If Not W_Ret Then
    Exit Sub
End If

On Error GoTo myerr


objSess.FindById("wnd[0]").maximize
objSess.FindById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/okcd").Text = "/ntm03" 'TM03
objSess.FindById("wnd[0]").SendVKey 0

objSess.FindById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtVTMFHA-BUKRS").Text = "0050" ' Company Code
objSess.FindById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtVTMFHA-RFHA").Text = Cells(currentline, 1).Value ' Referenze Nummer
objSess.FindById("wnd[0]").SendVKey 0

Cells(currentline, 6).Value = objSess.FindById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTS00/tabpBASE/ssubTS00_SUB:SAPLTM00:1203/ctxtVTMFHAZU-XVTRAB").Text ' Abschlussdatum
Cells(currentline, 9).Value = objSess.FindById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTS00/tabpBASE/ssubTS00_SUB:SAPLTM00:1203/txtVTMFHA-KONTRH").Text ' Geschäftspartner
Cells(currentline, 11).Value = objSess.FindById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTS00/tabpBASE/ssubTS00_SUB:SAPLTM00:1203/txtVTMHPTBWG-XZBETR").Text ' Zahlungsbetrag
Cells(currentline, 16).Value = objSess.FindById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTS00/tabpBASE/ssubTS00_SUB:SAPLTM00:1203/subDATES:SAPLTM00:0011/ctxtVTMFHAZU-XBLFZ").Text 'Laufzeit Beginn
Cells(currentline, 17).Value = objSess.FindById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTS00/tabpBASE/ssubTS00_SUB:SAPLTM00:1203/subDATES:SAPLTM00:0011/ctxtVTMFHAZU-XELFZ").Text 'Laufzeit Ende
Cells(currentline, 19).Value = objSess.FindById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTS00/tabpBASE/ssubTS00_SUB:SAPLTM00:1203/txtVTMHPTBWG-XNWHR").Text ' Nominalbetrag


' Setting the line status to completed
Cells(currentline, 2).Value = 1
Exit Sub

myerr:
' Some error occured
' Setting the line status to Failed
Cells(currentline, 2).Value = 2
    

End Sub

Sub StartExtract()
Dim currentline As Integer

    ' This is the system to connect to
    W_System = "Z2L100"
    ' We start looking for order numbers from line 8 in the sheet
    currentline = 8
    While Cells(currentline, 1).Value <> ""
        ' Only process this line if the status is "to be processed"
        If Cells(currentline, 2).Value = 0 Then
            ' Run the actual GUI script
            RunGUIScript currentline
        End If
        ' move to the next line
        currentline = currentline + 1
    Wend


    ' Update the current date and time
    Cells(2, 3).Value = Now()
    objSess.EndTransaction
    

   

End Sub
```

As you can see as the status is completed and if there is no more "Referenze Number" to search for, it stops. That's all right.

The second step is to take the "Referenze Number" (here I have to concatenate an ASTERISK to the "Referenze Number", example `[*12345]`) and the Closing Date, paste it into SAP search criteria, opens and getting the data from GridView and paste it back into the sheet.

Here is the SAP GUI Scripting generated code:

```
objSess.FindById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/okcd").Text = "/nse16"
objSess.FindById("wnd[0]").SendVKey 0
objSess.FindById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtDATABROWSE-TABLENAME").Text = "VTBFHAZU"
objSess.FindById("wnd[0]").SendVKey 0
objSess.FindById("wnd[0]").SendVKey 17
objSess.FindById("wnd[1]/usr/txtENAME-LOW").Text = ""
objSess.FindById("wnd[1]/usr/txtENAME-LOW").SetFocus
objSess.FindById("wnd[1]/usr/txtENAME-LOW").caretPosition = 0
objSess.FindById("wnd[1]/tbar[0]/btn[8]").Press
objSess.FindById("wnd[1]/usr/cntlALV_CONTAINER_1/shellcont/shell").CurrentCellRow = 2
objSess.FindById("wnd[1]/usr/cntlALV_CONTAINER_1/shellcont/shell").SelectedRows = "2"
objSess.FindById("wnd[1]/tbar[0]/btn[2]").Press
objSess.FindById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtI4-LOW").Text = "06.08.2018" ' CLOSING DATE
objSess.FindById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtI4-LOW").SetFocus
objSess.FindById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtI4-LOW").caretPosition = 10
objSess.FindById("wnd[0]").SendVKey 0
objSess.FindById("wnd[0]/usr/txtI14-LOW").Text = "*25750" ' ASTERIX (*) & REFERENZE NUMBER from Excel
objSess.FindById("wnd[0]/usr/txtI14-LOW").SetFocus
objSess.FindById("wnd[0]/usr/txtI14-LOW").caretPosition = 6
objSess.FindById("wnd[0]").SendVKey 0
objSess.FindById("wnd[0]").SendVKey 8

' Store The GridView As Local Object

Set GridView = objSess.FindById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlGRID1/shellcont/shell")
' Extract The Column Titles

For i = 0 To GridView.ColumnCount - 1
    Cells(9, i + 1).Value = GridView.GetColumnTitles(GridView.ColumnOrder(i))(0)
Next i
' Extract The Content

For i = 0 To GridView.ColumnCount - 1
   For j = 0 To GridView.RowCount - 1
       Cells(10 + j, i + 1).Value = GridView.GetCellValue(j, GridView.ColumnOrder(i))
   Next j
Next i
```

This code extracts me the Header name, additional 2 rows with 63 columns.
Actually I don't need all of the data. From the GridView, I ONLY need:

- row 1 column 3
- row 1 column 37

and

- row 2 column 3
- row 2 column 37

pasted back into the active Excel sheet row.  (see the attached picture)

Then the next "referenze nummber".

The Excel sheet:

[image: Excel-Where the data should be imported/pasted from the GridView]

It should not be complicated for someone who has programming skills.
I am hoping that someone will help me on this.

I didn't wrote the code above. I used the code and implemented it with my SAP GUI Recording and referencing to the cells into excel. The goal here is to implement all in one VBA module.

Thanks in advance !
Since this is my first post I hope you wont go harsh on me :)
I´ll stay here to learn with the experienced ones.
Thank you for sharing your knowledge!
Sharing is caring!

Cheers.

Comment: Someone a thought or suggestions ? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Hello everyone and thanks for the views.

After setting the GridView as Object, I used the function getCellValue. For the rows you need to use an index position and for the column the name of the column to get the cell value.

I ´ve solved the problem with this few lines of codes:

```
Set GridView = objSess.FindById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlGRID1/shellcont/shell") '-Store The GridView As Local Object

        Cells(currentline, 10) = GridView.GetCellValue(0, "RFHA")       '-Getting The Data From SAP GridView Into Excel
        Cells(currentline, 12) = GridView.GetCellValue(0, "KKURS")

        Cells(currentline, 20) = GridView.GetCellValue(1, "RFHA")
        Cells(currentline, 22) = GridView.GetCellValue(1, "KKURS")
```

Cheers.